# Ignore arguments for anonymous functions in capture operator in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I would like to create an anonymous function like: `fn _x -> "random" end` in a capture in Elixir, but if I do it like this:

`&("random")` then I get a compile error:

```
** (CompileError) invalid args for &, expected an expression in the format of &Mod.fun/arity, &local/arity or a capture containing at least one argument as &1, got: "random"
```

is there a way to achieve this? thanks

Comment: In theory you could do &("random" || &1) as a workaround, works for every truthy value

Comment: nice one @JulioGB! thanks everyone. I won't delete the question just because of Julio's suggesion, which can work for somebody else

Comment: Please don’t do it. It’s extremely counter-idiomatic, it’s hard to read, and after all it does not even save keystrokes compared to `fn _ -> :foo end`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is clearly stated in [the documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#&/1-anonymous-functions),

> The only restrictions when creating anonymous functions is that at least one placeholder must be present, i.e. it must contain at least `&1`, and that block expressions are not supported.

That said, `&("random")` notation is impossible and should be written as `fn _ -> "random" end`.